# heroku ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been trying to deploy an app on heroku and I have run into a lot of problems.  My current problem is that on sign up, I am getting an undefined method claiming that email is not a defined function for a Mate object.  I have run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

and

```
heroku restart
```

This does not seem to solve the problem.  Also when i go into the heroku terminal and look at a new Mate object, it has the email attribute.  Here are my heroku logs:

```
2013-07-14T22:38:29.637842+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2013-07-14T22:38:29.650497+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (9.1ms)
2013-07-14T22:40:36.729670+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/houses" for 71.202.122.134 at             2013-07-14 22:40:36 +0000
2013-07-14T22:40:36.803157+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Houses::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
2013-07-14T22:40:36.803157+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Fsl63CocaqA04/vhoDC0sU/CCSd2YGasqudyCleDNbc=", "house"=>{"address"=>"90 Castro", "city"=>"San Francisco", "email"=>"zyskowski.rob@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
2013-07-14T22:40:37.085467+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://frozen-spire-1369.herokuapp.com/mates/sign_up
2013-07-14T22:40:37.085467+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 282ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2013-07-14T22:40:37.266161+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Mates::RegistrationsController#new as HTML
2013-07-14T22:40:37.276199+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered mates/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.2ms)
2013-07-14T22:40:37.088159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/houses host=frozen-spire-1369.herokuapp.com fwd="71.202.122.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=368ms status=302 bytes=118
2013-07-14T22:40:37.282256+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/mates/sign_up host=frozen-spire-1369.herokuapp.com fwd="71.202.122.134" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=42ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     24:                     <div class="controls">
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     27:                </div>
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     28:    
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email' for #<Mate:0x007f2d5d8efc88>):
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     23:                     <%= f.label :email, :class => "control-label" %>
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-14T22:40:37.256850+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/mates/sign_up" for 71.202.122.134 at 2013-07-14 22:40:37 +0000
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/mates/registrations/new.html.erb:25:in `block in _app_views_mates_registrations_new_html_erb___482835816309687038_69916399610600'
2013-07-14T22:40:37.276313+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     22:                 <div class= "control-group">
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     25:                          <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "email" , :autofocus => true %>
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278470+00:00 app[web.1]:     26:                     </div>
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278704+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/mates/registrations/new.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_mates_registrations_new_html_erb___482835816309687038_69916399610600'
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278704+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-07-14T22:40:37.278704+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Im pretty stuck here so any ideas are much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: What is `Mate`? How was the `email` field ever added to the `mates` table? Is there a migration for that? Is that migration committed to version control? Did you push the latest commits to Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that `email` is blank in whatever view you're getting the error in. Write something like this in your view:

```
<%= @user.email if @user.email? %>
```